# Telnet-Like connection to server in Scala

Tags: java, sockets, scala, networking

I am trying to write a `Connector` class that will provide me with a text-based IO from and to a Server that itself only communicates in text. So, basically, a `telnet` clone. I have written this so far:

```
import java.net._
import scala.actors.Actor
import Actor._
import java.io._

class Connector(socket: Socket, handler: String => Unit) {
  private val out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream)
  private val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream))

  private val receiver = actor {
    var msg = in.readLine
    while (msg != null) {
      handler(msg)
      msg = in.readLine
    }
  }

  def print(msg: String) = out.println(msg)

  def close = {
    in.close
    out.close
  }
}
```

I now try to connect to a server with this (for testing)

```
import java.net._
import java.io._
import InetAddress.getByName

object Main extends App {
  val addr = getByName("wolfwings.us")
  val socket = new Socket(addr, 4000)

  val connector = new Connector(socket, ((msg) => println(msg)))

  val stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))

  var input = stdIn.readLine
  while(input != null) {
    connector.print(input)
    input = stdIn.readLine
  }

  stdIn.close
  connector.close
}
```

What happens is: It connects properly and sends me the greeting screen of the server. And then it stops in the middle of the text. When I now input, it outputs the last line of the greeting text, then the rest, minus the last line. And so on. Also, it puts extra `\n` behind every line. When I replace `println` with `print`, then there are no `\n`s suddenly.

From what I see this should all work fine and properly. I mean, it's not like a simple text IO like this is higher witchcraft? What hidden quirks did I not know here?

**EDIT**: Correction: After some trying and research, I found out that actually, the program only swallows the last line of the server responses. It seems like the server itself is sometimes not sending full lines, so of course the client would read them.

Comment: are you connecting to the server from Windows or Unix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it for myself, it seems I made a lot of assumptions that weren't met.

```
  private val receiver = actor {
    var done = false
    while (!done) {
      val n = in.read
      if(n < 0)
        done = true
      else
        handler(n.toChar)
    }
  }
```

Now it seems to work fine and I can continue.